# How to say "Please direct all your future correspondence to email"?

Tags: translation, business-japanese

Soon I am leaving my job and I would like to leave an e-mail for future correspondence with my colleagues. How do I write in Japanese something like "Please direct all your future correspondence to **my private email**"?

I could go with some simple expression like: 今からメールをemailへ書いていただけますか, but there probably exist better ways to express it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 今後何かありましたら、my email のほうにメールをお願いします。

Comment: This one is okay, is not what is asked in your question. It is requesting a mail to that email address in case something happens. It does not mean "If you are to send an email to me, please direct it to <my email>."

Comment: Sounds good. Many consider "ほうに" to be incorrect 敬語 though, so my suggestion would be "今後何かありましたら、My emailまでメールをお願いします。"

Comment: @sawa: I want to say that in case anybody needs something or will need to contact me (any future correspondence whatsoever) they can reach me at my private e-mail, since I will not have the company e-mail anymore. It's a standard practice where I come from to do so, so when an employee leaves a company, other people still have a means to communicate with him. Do you know of a good way to communicate this (other than what I wrote above)?

Answer (score 0):

The following should suffice:

> これからはこのアドレスにメールを送ってください。
>
> アドレス：abc@mail.com